# Is there an open interval on which f is monotone? explain why?

Tags: real-analysis

let f be continuous on R. Is there an open interval on which f is monotone? explain why?

Comment: but does a small range means open interval?!!

Comment: Sounds like homework, what did you try?

Comment: No, its not. One of my  colleague asked me.but I got it. Thank you

Comment: @user139865 It's the same thing or at the very least, it is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

No. Look up any example of a continuous nowhere differentiable function.

Comment: does this example works also if we are defining differentiability as the common finite value of the upper and lower derivatives?

Comment: How is that different from any other definition?

Comment: it is looking more complicated at least